# bash ldapsearch for mail attribute

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that pulls in an e-mail address from a file, and then does an ldapsearch query for the mail attribute.  I am having problems, and I think the "@" sign in the email address is the culprit

```
while IFS=, read uid user mail
do
    filter='(mail='"$mail"')'
    echo $filter
done < input.csv
```

I keep getting output like this:

```
)mail=user@company.com
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
(mail=user@company.com)
```

I appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is the carriage return (`\r` or `\x0d`) at the end of each line of your input.

You need to convert your csv file to unix-style line endings, or otherwise remove the trailing carriage return.

Use `hd` to see the output in hex, which might make what's going on more obvious (the `)` is being written on top of the `(`)